# Getting loop to work in my script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically want this loop to produce random spaces in a grid I am developing, but cannot get it to work in my script.

I have the correct loop I just can't get it to work with the rest of my script

I have just edited and it still doesn't work, any other ideas?

```
   var listOfWords = {};

var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");

var i;
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){
   listOfWords[ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word")] = {
         "pic" : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
         "audio" : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
   };
} 

console.log(listOfWords);

var chosenWords = new Array();

      for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length+1));
        chosenWords.push(listOfWords[rand]);
         if (chosenWords.length < 12){
                    chosenWords.push('  ');   
          }

    }

var shuffledWords = Object.keys(listOfWords).slice(0).sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).slice(0, 6);
var guesses = {};
console.log(shuffledWords);
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
 var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(shuffledWords).length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        guesses[word] = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');


            $(cell).addClass('drop').attr('data-word', word);
            cell.textContent = word[k];

            row.appendChild(cell);
           }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any errors or warnings?

Comment: Firebug can't find anything wrong @Liam McCann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you :

```
var listOfWords = [];

var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");

var i;
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){

   listOfWords.push({
         "name"   : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
         "pic"    : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
         "audio"  : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
   });

    console.log(listOfWords);
}

console.log(listOfWords);

var chosenWords = [];
var cpy_list = listOfWords.slice();

      for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cpy_list.length));
        console.log('push ' + cpy_list[rand].name);
        chosenWords.push(cpy_list[rand].name);
        cpy_list.splice(rand,1);
        console.log(cpy_list);  
        if (chosenWords.length < 12){
            console.log('make a blanck' );
                    chosenWords.push('   ');   
          }

    }

console.log(chosenWords);
var shuffledWords = [];
 shuffledWords = chosenWords.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });

var guesses = {};
console.log(shuffledWords);
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    console.log(shuffledWords);
    for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        console.log(j);
        console.log(word);
        guesses[word] = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');


            $(cell).addClass('drop').attr('data-word', word);
            cell.textContent = word[k];

            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);

$('#pickNext').click(function() {
    // remove the class from all td's
    $('td').removeClass('spellword');
    // pick a random word
    rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
    // apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
    $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('spellword');
});



$('.drag').draggable({

    helper: 'clone',
    snap: '.drop',
    grid: [60, 60],
    revert: 'invalid',
    snapMode: 'corner'
});


$('.drop').droppable ({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        word = $(this).data('word');

        guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));
        console.log($(event));
        console.log($(ui.draggable).text());

        console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


        if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

            $(this).addClass('wordglow3');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('wordglow');
        }
        console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


        console.log(guesses);

        if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
            if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
                $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass('wordglow2');

            } else {
                $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");
                guesses[word].splice(0, guesses[word].length);
            }
        }






    },


    activate: function(event, ui) {
        word = $(this).data('word');

        // try to remove the class
        $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3');
    }


});

$(".minibutton").hover(function (){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    },function(){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
    }
);


$(".minibutton2").hover(function (){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    },function(){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
    }
);


var audio = $("#mysoundclip")[0];
$("button").click(function() {
    var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
    if (noExist) {
        $('#pickNext').click();
    } else {

        $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
        audio.play();
    }
});

var audio = $("#mysoundclip")[0];
$("button2").click(function() {
    var noExist = $('td[data-word=' +  listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
    if (noExist) {
        $('#pickNext').click();
    } else {

        $("#mysoundclip").attr('src',  listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
        audio.play();
    }
});

var pic = $("#mypic")[0];
$("button").click(function() {
    var noExist = $('td[data-word=' +  listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
    if (noExist) {
        $('#pickNext').click();
    } else {

        pic = $("#mypic").attr('src',  listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
        pic.show();
    }
});


function keys(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keys.push(key);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

​

Comment: Thanks so much but the thing wrong with it is that it doesn't show images and give the sounds when the "next" button is pressed, some of the blanks arn't filled with background color and words repeat in the grid. @cedric.salaun

Comment: i have update my code. correction of :
- some of the blanks arn't filled with background color and words repeat in the grid. [test on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBzPx/1/)

Comment: Thanks @cedric.salaun any idea how to stop the "next" button highlighting the empty spaces?

Answer (score 0):

First you should change :

```
 If(chosenWords.length < 12){
```

to :

```
 if (chosenWords.length < 12) {
```

and :

```
 chosenWords.push(“  ”);
```

to :

```
 chosenWords.push(' ');
```

and define the variable chosenWords.

Comment: you forget ';' on the line 'var guesses = {}' and you still have 'If' instead of 'if'

Comment: Still doesnt work. Look... http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/bEYJH/28/ It is supposed to make a 6x6 grid - half empty space and half words with linked sounds and images. @cedric.salaun

Comment: you treat listOfWords like a list but it's an object.

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated. I will upvote you when I get to 15